# How to open a new tab from a Firefox WebExtension as if the user clicked + to open a new tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've tried the following:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
{ 
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "about:newtab"
    });         
});
```

Unfortunately, I can not open the new tab page `about:newtab` with `tabs.create()`. It throws a security error:

```
Security Error: Content at moz-extension://5cdd4429-f725-49c4-bdc1-547e1acc085b/ may not load or link to about:newtab.
```

How am I suppose to open `about:newtab` from a Firefox WebExtension?

Comment: That's interesting, it seems like it should work. Did you try a url other then `about:newtab`? You might need to request permissions in the manifest.json

Comment: Thanks. Permission is "http://*/*", "https://*/*"

Comment: I added <all_url> but it does not allow about:newtab and chrome://. Only about:blank is allowed. Google Chrome is less strict about this. Any advice?

Comment: Try passing in to `url` parameter, it will probably open `about:newtab`. I'll ask some webext folk what perms you'll need for `chrome://`.

Comment: Thanks Noitidart but I did not understand what is "try passing in to url parameter". Can you post a code?

Comment: Oh typo, whoops, I mean this: `chrome.tabs.create();`

Comment: Thanks mate but create does not work without passing a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`about:newtab` is considered a privileged `about` page. You can not *explicitly* open it using `tabs.create()`.  However, you can open a tab to display the default page for a new tab. Normally this default page will be `about:newtab`.

To open the default page for a new tab, you can pass an object to [`tabs.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create) that does not contain a [`url` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/create#Parameters).

For example, to open a new tab in the current window at the index which would be used if the user clicked on the `+` icon to open a new tab, you could use the following:

```
chrome.tabs.create({});
```

To open a new tab at `index=1` in the current window, you could do:

```
chrome.tabs.create({index: 1});
```

By default, the page that you will open is `about:newtab`.  However, the user may have installed another extension that changes the page used for a new tab. If so, that page will be used.